# Sanity real-time update is not working on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, sanity

I'm tring to listen documents in sanity but getting this error
`TypeError: Cannot read property '_nativeModule' of undefined, js engine: hermes`

this is the part of my code that causing the error

```
const query = `*[_type == 'order']`;
    const subscription = client.listen(query).subscribe((update) => {
      console.log("result===>", update.result);
});
```